# Animation Resets when Shape Properties are changed in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a shape named `box1` in my first slide. It has no animations attached to it. However, there are other shapes on the slide that contain lots of trigger animation sequences. If I run the macro `ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("box1").Top = 400` the trigger animation state doesn't change. If I had changed the colour of some other shape via the trigger animation, it stays the same. It is perfect, only the position of `box1` changes.

Now, if any animation is attached to `box1` and the same macro is played, the animate state of the entire slide resets.

I tried using `GetClickCount` but that always remained 0 as the animations were all part of trigger sequences. I would appreciate any and all help on this front.

Thank you very much.